# Print invidivual names and values of ${headerValues} using EL in JSP

Tags: jsp, http-headers, el

I am trying to print the implicit EL object `${headerValues}` in a JSP page as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    ${headerValues}
  </body>
</html>
```

However, it prints the following output:

> javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects$8@19255988

How can I print the individual header names and values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a `Map<String, String[]>`. So, you need to iterate over it in order to access the entries. You can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:forEach>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) for this. Every iteration will give you a [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) which in turn has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods. The `getKey()` will return the header name. The `getValue()` will return the header values as a `String[]`. You'd need another `<c:forEach>` to iterate over it.

In a nutshell:

```
<dl>
    <c:forEach items="${headerValues}" var="entry">
        <dt>${entry.key}</dt>
        <c:forEach items="${entry.value}" var="headerValue">
            <dd>${headerValue}</dd>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
</dl>
```